# How to post form using ajax in popup without reload page in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

> Here is MY Ajax Code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contactForm").submit(function(e){
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var phone_no = $("#phone_no").val();
        var alt_ph_no = $("#alt_ph_no").val();
        var id_card_number = $("#id_card_number").val();
        var email_id = $("#email_id").val();
        var address = $("#address").val();
        $.ajax({ 
            method: 'POST', 
            url: "<?php echo url('admin/customer_add') ?>", 
            async: false,
            data: "&name=" + name + "&phone_no=" + phone_no + "&alt_ph_no=" + alt_ph_no + "&id_card_number=" + id_card_number + "&email_id=" + email_id + "&address=" + address +  "_token=" + $('#token').val(),
            success: function(result){
                if (result == "success"){
                    alert("Done");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

> My Controller

```
public function customer_add(Request $request)
    {
        // dd($request);
        Customer::create([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'phone_no' => $request->input('phone_no'),
            'alt_ph_no' => $request->input('alt_ph_no'),
            'id_card_number' => $request->input('id_card_number'),
            'email_id' => $request->input('email_id'),
            'address' => $request->input('address'),
            'date_con' => now(),
        ]);
    }
```

> When i submit this form values is store in DB but page reload on this
>   URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/customer_add i want form is submit and
>   page not reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  **e.preventDefault();** if you don't want to reload.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contactForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var phone_no = $("#phone_no").val();
        var alt_ph_no = $("#alt_ph_no").val();
        var id_card_number = $("#id_card_number").val();
        var email_id = $("#email_id").val();
        var address = $("#address").val();
        $.ajax({ 
            method: 'POST', 
            url: "<?php echo url('admin/customer_add') ?>", 
            async: false,
            data: "&name=" + name + "&phone_no=" + phone_no + "&alt_ph_no=" + alt_ph_no + "&id_card_number=" + id_card_number + "&email_id=" + email_id + "&address=" + address +  "_token=" + $('#token').val(),
            success: function(result){
                if (result == "success"){
                    alert("Done");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

**Or**

```
$('body').on('submit','#contactForm',function(e){

                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url : "{{ url('admin/customer_add') }}",
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: false,       
                    cache: false,             
                    processData:false, 
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                     },
                    beforeSend: function(){
                      //loding..
                    },
                    success:function(result){
                     if (result == "success"){
                          $('#modal').modal('hide');
                      }



                    },

                });
            });
```

Comment: NOw its work bro. Can you make after value save in DB then pop close and value is show in drop down list which i was saved ?

Comment: You can do `$('#modal').modal('hide');` if you are using boostrap model..or ajax datatable reload if you're getting rows from datatable.

Comment: Where i add this $('#modal').modal('hide'); ? i will select your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197551/discussion-between-dilip-hirapara-and-zeeshan).

Comment: into success function.